# Open SlideUpPanel OnClickListener from a drawer NULL Pointer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am a beginner developing a geolocation app using google map V2, navigation drawer and SlideUpPanel from [AndroidSlidingUpPanel Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
In my MapsActivity I have a public class "MyAdapter" where am using a custom row.
when I want to use the Sliding Layout (mLayout) into my adapter class to open the slide up panel onClickListener, android studio cannot resolve symbol 'layout'.

how can I call this layout into my adapter ?
sorry for my bad english

```
class MyAdpater extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context ;
String [] telecentreAurillac;
int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,
        R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur,R.drawable.ic_pointeur};


public MyAdpater (Context context) {

    this.context=context;

    telecentreAurillac = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.telecentreAurillac);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return telecentreAurillac.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return telecentreAurillac[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View row = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    }
    else
    {
        row = convertView;
    }
    // Relier avec custom row
    TextView titleTextView =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TelecentreTexViewDrawer);
    ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageDrawer);
    //affichage pour chaque position
    titleTextView.setText(telecentreAurillac[position]);
    titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);


    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null);


    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("MapsActivity", "clickOnTV");



            // drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            mLayout.setAnchorPoint(1.0f);
            // mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
            mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);


        }
    });

    return row;

}
```

}

In my main activity

```
    mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    //Log.i("test test", mLayout.toString());
    mLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelExpanded");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelCollapsed");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelAnchored");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelHidden(View panel) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelHidden");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easy way would be making it static and accessing it like:

```
 Activity.mlayout..
```

But the correct way would be sending the object reference via constructor argument like:

```
public MyAdpater (Context context, SlidingUpPanel mlayout) {

this.mlayout = mlayout;
this.context=context;

telecentreAurillac = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.telecentreAurillac);
```

}

and even better way would be to handle clicks to listview items in Activity itself:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
      mLayout.setAnchorPoint(1.0f); 
        // mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN); 
        mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your 3 advices but i still not working  [picture with error message](http://hpics.li/db84ac7)  [second one](http://hpics.li/db84ac7) [the last](http://hpics.li/4cab641)

Comment: Go for the third one and use a debugger to check if all is executing well.

Comment: am getting an error with setOnItemClickListener (Error:(426, 41) error: illegal start of type) when I used ( Log.i("MapsActivity", "clickOnItem"); ) into OnItemClick without setOnitemClickListener am getting nothing when I click

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      Log.i("MapsActivity", "clickOnItem");
                mLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);
            }
        });

Comment: You have 2 setOnItemClickListener(..), and that to nested

Comment: you can see my code in the last picture of my first comment